# How do you password protect entering the vba code editor from a sheet?

Tags: security, excel, vba, passwords

I want a method that will password protect my vba code, so that users in the sheet won't be able to go into the code editor without entering it.

Comment: ?? can you edit and rephrase the question, this is not clear...

Comment: I have a vba project with code written on it..when other users opens the sheet he or she can open it but when he or she want to 'view code' den a password protect message will appear..he or she will have to enter the correct password to view the code..Plz can u giv me the code

Comment: That's not done by code. That is done by using the VBE menus.

Comment: Can you decribe me the details

Comment: @michelle: every menu is described step by step in the first link i gave you in my answer. Have a look !

Comment: This question belongs on SuperUser.

Answer (score 2):

You can protect your vba code by a password as described here: http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/protect-vba-code.htm

But this is not the most secure way to protect your code, see this thread for more information: [Lock down Microsoft Excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760981/lock-down-microsoft-excel-macro/6762946#6762946)

Comment: @michelle: please, have a look at the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and write in full english. Next, have a look at the link i gave you, there is no vba code to use