# How to give link to sheet1 after created the userform in developer menu in excel?

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a userform and designed a small application in VBA for Excel and saved the file as a macro enabled Excel sheet.

How can I display the application form on the first sheet?  It should display the sheet when the file is opened, and I don't want to go to developer menu to see the userform.

Also, how can I hide the code from others?  I have seen 'Protection' under the Tools menu, but it's blocking the full userform. I only want to hide the code, not the form.

Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the Workbook_Open() to launch the userform.

Answer (score 0):

Since the answers are in the format of edit I will just give direct forward Web links to indicate the question is answered. I really agree with the above two authors. This is not really a question to be asked in this forum, when you can easily find so many ways to find a solution. Plus the title is misleading too. No offense.

http://www.automateexcel.com/2004/08/13/excel_vba_show_or_load_a_form_when_excel/

[How do you password protect entering the vba code editor from a sheet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6787544/how-do-you-password-protect-entering-the-vba-code-editor-from-a-sheet)

http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/spreadsheet_protection_faq1/

_m on mobile and unable to do hyperlink quoting.