# Hide macro from user in Excel but still call via button?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a spreadsheet that will be distributed to co-workers; I want to make it as user friendly as possible so in order to run the macros I have a simple button that automates everything for them. But I don't want them to have access to running any of the macros on their own.

I've managed to somewhat do this using

```
Option Private Module
Public Sub Run_Batch_Report()
'The actual script that works is here, cutting it to skip to the portion that won't work'
Call Misc_Doc
MsgBox ("Report finished.")
End Sub
```

All that Public Sub Misc_Doc() does is import data from another spreadsheet and format it.

And then having a Command Button calling the module via application.run

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Application.Run "Batching_Module.Run_Batch_Report"
End Sub
```

Doing this *kind* of works; as in it seems to run the Run_Batch_Report sub just fine, but that sub also calls other subs within the same module to complete the job. Those subs will not run UNLESS I unlock the VB in developers options for viewing and editing. Is it possible to have the sub run in its entirety (including calling other subs within the same module) or would I have to restructure my sub to just include all the other subs it calls as well?

Sorry if I worded this haphazardly - I'm actually in the middle of a meeting and juggling this while listening to the bosses.

Edit: To clarify, I've locked the VB from being viewed. When I run the script while it's still locked, it won't allow the sub to call other portions of the module. Once my password is entered to unlock VB for viewing, it works.

Comment: You could make it so that the button code sets a global Boolean variable (e.g. call it `Enabled`) equal to true. All other subs exit immediately if this variable isn't true. All exit points to your subs can set the variable equal to false. If other users try to run a sub other than through the button -- nothing happens.

Comment: Take the time to [edit] your post to make a clear problem statement. As it stands, I've no idea what the problem is, or how `Run_Batch_Report` could possibly "not run other subs" unless the VBE is "unlocked" (it's not *locked*, anyone can press Alt+F11 anytime to bring it up). Possible you need to *restructure your sub*, but you haven't included any of it, so how could we know?

Comment: FWIW that `Application.Run` call is not needed. Why couldn't the click handler just do `Run_Batch_Report`? `Option Private Module` has no effect whatsoever on member accessibility. It merely *hides* public members from the host application's *macros* list, or available UDF's. Also you should avoid underscores in member names, and stick to `PascalCase`, e.g. `RunBatchReport`.

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760981/lock-down-microsoft-excel-macro

Comment: I've edited a little to hopefully make my problem more clear. I'm still relatively new to VB and kind of picking up as I go.

Comment: Thanks for editing. Locking the project from being viewed is more of a hinderance for the dev (you!) than it is for anyone that actually wants to get to the code. I have a pinned macro in my "recent documents" that unlocks any locked VB project in a few milliseconds. There's no point wrecking your brains over it. VBA is not secure, period.

Comment: So just to further clarify, `Misc_Doc` doesn't run unless the project is unlocked? Or is it the `Application.Run "Batching_Module.Run_Batch_Report"` call that doesn't?

Comment: It's `Misc_Doc` that doesn't run.
`Application.Run "Batching_Module.Run_Batch_Report` works just fine, but the final part of `Run_Batch_Report` calls `Misc_Doc` and that's the part that won't run. The `MsgBox ("Report finished.")` works just fine though, so it's almost as if the `Call` command is skipped all together.

Comment: Is `Misc_Doc` in the same module? Or is it `Public` in another module? Seems you're running in circles jumping around on your left foot while grabbing your ear and trying to eat your elbow, just to draw attention from that big flashy arrow-shaped neon sign pointing to that procedure you don't want anyone to see. Specify `Option Explicit` at the top of every module - does your code still compile?

Comment: Also, you mentioned that I should be able to just have the handler `Run_Batch_Report` when clicked, but that's in another module, that's why I'm using `Application.run` though I have tried using just `Call Batching_Module.Run_Batch_Report` and it's had the same outcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming "But I don't want them to have access to running any of the macros on their own" stands for "I don't want the macros to be listed in the 'Macros' window", you already have that.

I can't reproduce your "macro doesn't run unless project is unlocked" issue, with or without `Application.Run` getting involved, not sure what that's about. In any case, you seem to be under the false impression that password-protecting your project gives it any kind of security. It doesn't.

> **VBA code is not secure**. VBA project password protection is literally a joke, it only annoys the dev (you!) and prevents clueless users that wouldn't know what to do with the VBE anyway, from viewing source code that they wouldn't understand anyway - and if someone wants to see the code, trust me, they will - [in a matter of seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508116/1188513).
>
> If someone can open the host document, they can get to the VBA code.

Either a user can run the macro, or they can't. If a user can click a button to invoke some VBA code, then they have permission to invoke that VBA code from anywhere.

Have your "hidden" macros in a standard module (.bas) with `Option Private Module` specified:

```
Option Private Module
Option Explicit

Public Sub SomeHiddenMacro()
    MsgBox "Hi"
End Sub
```

And then you can still assign that macro to some *shape*, by typing the macro's name (it's not going to be listed, because `Option Private Module`):

[image: Excel's "Assign Macro" dialog]

Click the button, see it work:

[image: Message box shows up]

Shapes can be formatted to look much prettier than any ActiveX button:

[image: "Run batch report" button with gradient shading and 3D bevel]

It doesn't need to be any more complicated than that.

---

#### The Classy Solution

You're beginning with VBA, so I presume you haven't toyed with class modules much. One of the nice things about class modules is that their public members can't be invoked as macros, because class modules don't exist at run-time - they're *types*, not *modules*. For a *type* to mean anything, it needs to be *instantiated* - and the macro runner doesn't do that.

So put the "worker" code in a class module, say `BatchReport`:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Run()
    'TODO: do your thing
End Sub
```

Now in the macro that's attached to the button (or in the ActiveX button's `Click` handler), all you do is create an instance of that object with the `New` keyword, and invoke its `Run` method:

```
Option Private Module
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunBatchReport()
    With New BatchReport
        .Run
    End With
End Sub
```

Here I'm having a `With` block hold the object reference. Alternatively you could have declared an object variable, and `Set` its reference to a `New` instance of the `BatchReport` class:

```
Option Private Module
Option Explicit

Public Sub RunBatchReport()
    Dim report As BatchReport
    Set report = New BatchReport
    report.Run
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it is helpful. I understand that password protection can easily be broken, but I don't expect anyone to try prying that hard into it. It isn't that big of a deal but a specific preference that I have.

However I'm still confused as to why password protecting makes my script only partially run but once I unlock it, the script works just fine.

Comment: As I said, I can't reproduce this issue... but IMO it's moot. You'll quickly get sick of constantly typing that password. And *cracking it is not hard at all*. I have that linked code in a pinned macro-enabled workbook which I called `CrackerJack.xlsm`; whenever I need to crack a VBA password I just open that and type `CrackItOpen` in the immediate pane, and boom, unlocked. 2 seconds.

Comment: Another example of why it's fairly moot: I built it into an Add in called `Break Things.xla` which includes a ribbon. Now whenever I want to open the code I just click a button on the ribbon and I'm in.