# How do I prevent others from editing Excel Macro Code(read-only)

Tags: excel, vba

I want to be able to have other users of an excel file look at, but not modify the code used in an excel sheet (for transparency and security reasons).

*I realize similar questions have been asked on SO before, but those deal with hiding the source code, which I want to avoid.*

Is there any way I can basically put a macro on read-only?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lock down Microsoft Excel macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6760981/lock-down-microsoft-excel-macro)

Comment: @DannyPapadopulos I addressed this in the second sentence. I want the source to remain visible, i.e read only

Comment: I don't think that's possible. You could lock the macros completely and have a macro inside that would save all modules as text files for example once the Workbook is opened. Or something of that sort.

Comment: You can't. If you lock the modules with a password then a hex editor can be used to bypass that. If the user can open the workbook then there's nothing you can do except  make it more difficult.

Comment: Locking the modules sounds like enough for your situation